# Checking an element is absent using WebRat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, webrat

The following works just fine:

```
Then /^I should see a button called "([^\"]*)"$/ do |name|
  response.should have_selector("li") do |li|
    li.should have_selector("a") do |a|
      a.should contain(name)
    end
  end
end
```

Now I need to complement it with a step like this:

```
Then /^I should not see a button called "([^\"]*)"$/ do |name|
   [snip...]
end
```

The standard "And I should not see" is not satisfactory, as it will pick up the target phrase anywhere in the page -- not just within buttons. I specifically need to check that no button with the target text are present.

My first instinct was to try something like this:

```
Then /^I should see a button called "([^\"]*)"$/ do |name|
  response.should have_selector("li") do |li|
    li.should have_selector("a") do |a|
      a.should_not contain(name)
    end
  end
end
```

But of course that will pass as long as there's any button on the page that does not include the target text, even if there are also one or more buttons that do include the target text.

Your thoughts?

Many thanks,

Steven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! I gave every control a class of "control", then wrote
this step definition:

```
Then /^I should not see a control called "([^\"]*)"$/ do |name|
  response.should have_selector("a.control", :content => name, :count
=> 0)
end
```

Of course, this presumes I'm happy giving them all a class of
"control"...

s.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `assert_not_contain` (and maybe `not_contain` but I doubt it as it's not in the [rdoc](http://gitrdoc.com/brynary/webrat/tree/master/)).

```
a.should assert_not_contain(name)
```

Comment: yep, assert_not_contain(name) is the method you want if you take this approach.

Comment: Actually, not so quickly...

but I can't paste code into a comment box, so I'm continuing over in the WebRat Google Group.

Comment: Well you can update your question with the additionnal informations.

Answer (score 0):

Are your buttons actually links? For buttons (where there is a submit value), I use:

```
assert_have_selector "input[type=submit][value=\"#{text}\"]"
```

and:

```
assert_have_no_selector "input[type=submit][value=\"#{text}\"]"
```

hth.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Technically they are links. I'm just calling them buttons because that's how they appear in the interface.

Comment: You got me thinking. I've just changed "button" to "control" in all my tests.